# set disabled efect on background-image

Tags: css

How I can set a grey transparent layer as a disabled effect using  `background-image` the ways  I tried didn't work

```
.coupon{
          background-image: url("../images/coupon-bg-yellow.jpg");
          width: 243px !important;
          height: 419px !important;
          background-size: cover;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `opacity: 0.5;` to make the background image semi transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
  filter: grayscale(100%);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a pseudo class when the `disabled` attribute is active?

```css
.coupon { 
   position: relative; 
}
.coupon[disabled=true]:after {
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   
}
```